# How are these two declarations for static variables in C different?

Tags: c, static

why this code --https://onlinegdb.com/AJUXuxMwt prints **908080**
but if this code https://onlinegdb.com/ft4zurpP4 prints **908081**??
How are these two declarations different, if they are not then why different outputs?-

```
#include <stdio.h>
int fun();
static int i = 10;
int main()
{ 
    static int i = 90;
    
    printf("Hello World %d\n",i);
    fun();
    fun();

    return 0;
}
int fun()
{
    
    static int i=80;
     
    printf("%d \n",i);
    i++;
    
    return 0;
}
```

1. static int i=80;
2. static int i;
   i=80;

I am a novice in C, just started but can not clear this one up.

Comment: Please post all code in the question itself and not as external links.

Comment: The first example only sets `i` to `80` once no matter how many times the function is called because static initialisation by definition occurs only once. The second example resets `i` back to `80` every time the function is called..

Comment: The first declaration statically initializes `i`, i.e. it places the value `80` in the data segment where `i` resides.  The second sequence implicitly initializes `i` to `0`, then *assigns* `80` to `i` every time the assignment statement is reached.

Comment: @TomKarzes OH! This makes a lot of sense. Thank you very much!!! Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all it does not print `908081` only

```
Hello World 90
80 
81
```

Explanation.

When you are declaring the static automatic variable (local variable in function scope) it is initialized only **once** and keeps the value between the function calls.

1. `static int i=80;` - Initalization happens only once, then `i` keeps its value between the function calls. If you increase the `i` in your code the, the increased value will be kept when you call the function again.
2. `static int i; i = 80;` In this case it is not initialization only normal assignment. Every time the function is call the assignment `i = 80;` is executed, and `i` will have value of `80` after it.